# Redirect https to http except onepagecheckout in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect all my https to http except for this below url.

https://uae.example.com/ae_en/onepagecheckout/

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$onepagecheckout
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This code is working and redirecting all https to http but it seems my 2nd RewriteCond is not working. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/onepagecheckout [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Use `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable instead of `%{REQUEST_URI}` with correct regex pattern.

Comment: Searching for hours for this. For some reason Apache sometimes changes `%{REQUEST_URI}` . I had a similar situation where I wanted to redirect everything except one directory to HTTPS, and I could see it responded differently to the exception directory but still tried to redirect it to HTTPS.